# Is there any way to see a digest of what resources civilizations / city states own?

Tags: civilization-5

For example, I would like to get my hand on some pearls. A simple way to do that is to trade with other civilizations or to increase my influence with some city-state; the problem is that I can never remember who has what resource, not to mention that can constantly change.

Right now I'm using the diplomacy screen to go over each civilization and each city-state manually, clicking on them to check what they have - that's 3 click per civilization, 1 click per city-state. Is there any easier way to do that?

Also I would be interested in anything that allows me to see how much gold each civilization helps, it would be useful when I have some extra resources lying around and what to get some gold out of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The diplomacy summary that you get from clicking the scroll in the upper right will show you all the civs and city states at once, as well as what resources they have available, how much gold they have, and how much gold per turn they are making.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.