# Providing resources to cities when requested

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to see a digest of what resources civilizations / city states own?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8131/is-there-any-way-to-see-a-digest-of-what-resources-civilizations-city-states-ow)

Hi,

When one of your cities demands a luxury resource is there an easy way of finding other cities with which you can trade this resource?  I find myself randomly clicking on other cities in a hope they have this resource available to trade which leads me to think I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see what other Civs and/or City States have things to trade with you (or in the case of City States share with you if you become allied) from the "Diplomacy Overview" screen.

**Either** pull open the "quick" diplomacy view (top-right) and hit the button at the top of the pop up.

**Or** there's a menu button near the top-right as well, which gives access to several overview windows (Diplomacy, Military, Economic, etc).